# Conditional finishlocations based on variables from a Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, pagereference

I am invoking a Flow through a VF page. In the end I want to send the user either to the original record or the one they have just created, based upon another variable. As it is now, the user will always go to the location ending with the VarPrimeRecID Flow variable. But I would like it to go to a location ending with the VarNewRecID Flow variable if the VarLevel Flow variable = "Low".

The current Apex is this :

```
public class New_Flow_Controller2 {
    public Id recordId {get;set;}
    public flow.interview.First_Product_Review myflow {get;set;}
    public String risklevel {get;set;}

    public New_Flow_Controller2(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordId');
        risklevel = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('VarVendorRiskLevel');

    } 

    public String getendID() {        
        if (risklevel = 'Low') return myflow.VarVendProdRecID;

        if (myflow !=null) return myflow.VarNewReviewRecID;

        else return '/home/home.jsp';
    }       

    public PageReference getFinishLocation() {        

            PageReference endlocation = new PageReference('/' + getendID());           

        return endlocation;
    }
}
```

It seems easy enough, but I was coming into problems trying to base the PageReference on variable.

The line which is causing the problem is:

```
if (risklevel = 'Low') return myflow.VarVendProdRecID;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Condition expression must be of type Boolean.

I can't figure out how to pass that logic through that section.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a leading slash in `'home/home.jsp'`? Also you could just use `'/'` for the home page. What sort of problems did you experience. Can you [edit] your post to be more specific?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - thank you for your input. I have added the code which is currently preventing me from saving it. I also added some text after the code to try and explain what's happening. (I also added a leading slash to the /home/home.jsp....I guess I never got an error from that because it has never needed it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare equality using double equals (`==`), not single equals (`=`).

```
// Parens not necessary, just emphasis/clarity
Boolean isEqual;    

isEqual = (riskLevel == 'Low')
// compile successful

isEqual = (riskLevel = 'Low')
// compile error
```

Or use `.equals(...)`, but lead with the hard-coded string since you know it is non-null.

```
Boolean isEqual = 'Low'.equals(riskLevel)
```

Since that is a case-sensitive comparison and `==` is case-*insensitive*, you may also wish to use `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`, depending on your needs.

```
Boolean isEqual = 'Low'.equalsIgnoreCase(riskLevel)
```

Comment: thank you very much for that. I didn't even noticed that I had not included the double = signs. However, I now am getting a URL error when trying to get to VarVendProdRecID as the finishlocation. ("URL no longer exists"). I confirmed that the variable is indeed pulling a legit record ID. Do you have any ideas on that ?

Comment: Sounds like a new question. :) It's not a useful format to the forum if we keep adding new problems to the same question. Ends up being really hard to follow.